# asp.net ajax control toolkit slider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Iam using ajax controltoolkit slider i want to restrict the slider to a certain range.

Fr ex: my slider minvalue is 0 & maxvalue is 10000, but i can scroll only upto say 7000, 
my slider must move from 0 to 7000 but the range bar must be 10000.
Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event for the slider called OnClientDrag, what you can do is create a jquery/javascript function which will check the value upon changing and when it reaches 7000 you can cancel the event via a jquery method, something like this might help:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Slider1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" style="right:0px" Text="0"/>
        <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server"
            BehaviorID="Slider1"
            TargetControlID="Slider1"
            Minimum="-100"
            Maximum="100"
            BoundControlID="Slider1_BoundControl"
            Steps="5" />

        <input id="btnDisable" type="button" value="Disable" onclick="disableSlider()"/>
        <input id="btnEnable" type="button" value="Enable" onclick="enableSlider()" disabled="true"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function disableSlider(){
                 $clearHandlers($find('Slider1')._handle);
                 $clearHandlers($find('Slider1')._railElement);
                 $get('btnDisable').disabled = true;
                 $get('btnEnable').disabled = false;
            }
            function enableSlider(){
                 $addHandlers($find('Slider1')._handle, 
                    {
                        'mousedown': $find('Slider1')._onMouseDown,
                        'dragstart': $find('Slider1')._IEDragDropHandler,
                        'drag': $find('Slider1')._IEDragDropHandler,
                        'dragend': $find('Slider1')._IEDragDropHandler
                    },
                    $find('Slider1'));

                $addHandlers($find('Slider1')._railElement,
                    {
                        'click': $find('Slider1')._onRailClick
                    },
                    $find('Slider1'));
                $get('btnDisable').disabled = false;
                $get('btnEnable').disabled = true;
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```